# Give the name of all the teacher who does not teach math

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two tables. One is the `Course` table and the second is the `Teacher` table. I want to get all `Teacher` who does not teach `'Math'`. How can I do this?

Course Table

```
course_id   course  teacher_id  marks
 1          Physics     1        60
 2          Math        1        60
 3          Chemestry   1        60
 4          English     2        60
 5          Hindi       2        60
 6          Physics     2        60
 7          Chemestry   3        60
 8          English     4        60
 9          Math        5        60
10          Math        6        60
```

Teacher Table

```
teacher_id  name      salary    gender
   1       Teacher1    20         1
   2       Teacher2    30         1
   3       Teacher3    40         2
   4       Teacher4    50         2
   5       Teacher5    60         1
   6       Teacher6    70         2
```

Comment: You have to use a `JOIN`, there are many tutorials out there.
Tinker around with join and post your query if you can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Use 'Foreign Key' in Course Table field of 'teacher_id'. So it makes the code to move clearly without JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get all teacher who does not teachs math.

You need to join both the tables on **teacher_id** and then filter out the rows based on the **course**.

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT t.name
  2  FROM course c,
  3    teacher t
  4  WHERE c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
  5  AND c.course     <> 'Math';

NAME
--------
Teacher2
Teacher1
Teacher4
Teacher3

SQL>
```

**EDIT** Since you have teachers teaching multiple courses, you need to filter out further:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT c.*,
  3      t.name
  4    FROM course c,
  5      teacher t
  6    WHERE c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
  7    AND c.course      <> 'Math'
  8    )
  9  SELECT DISTINCT name
 10  FROM data
 11  WHERE teacher_id NOT IN
 12    (SELECT teacher_id FROM course WHERE course = 'Math'
 13    )
 14  /

NAME
--------
Teacher2
Teacher4
Teacher3

SQL>
```

**NOTE** Please keep in mind that the other solution using **NOT EXISTS** clause is better in terms of performance, since the table scans are less and even index scans. With proper indexes, the not exists query would be an optimal method.

Comment: If a teacher teaches 2 courses of which one of maths this fails.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I missed that. Updated the solution.

Comment: Can't you just write not exists and be done with it? You're doing 4 full table scans instead of one table scan and a couple of index range.

Comment: @Ben I don't think so it could be done in a single query using not exists. Because I don't see any key to join with.

Comment: You join with teacher ID everywhere else; why wouldn't you use the same?

Comment: @Ben I might be seriously missing something silly here, but `NOT EXISTS` would suppress all the rows if joined with teacher_id column.

Comment: @LalitKumarB +1 for the valuable information regarding SQLFiddle direct text to DDL

Comment: Sorry @Lalit; work got in the way but [knagaev](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29667766/458741) has done it.

Comment: @Ben I see and understood what you were saying. The and part in the not exists subquery made me bang my head. Just didn't struck that trivial thing. I feel terrible :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from teacher t 
where not exists 
(select 1 from course c where c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id and c.course = 'Math')
```

@LalitKumarB
Ben is absolutely right

Comment: I see. I added a note in case.

Answer (score 0):

inner join

```
select t.teacher_id, t.name
from teacher t, Course c 
where c.course='math' and t.teacher_id=c.teacher_id;
```

**EDIT**

you can do it using join and subquery.

```
select * from course join teacher 
on course.teacher_id=teacher.teacher_id
where teacher.teacher_id not in 
(select distinct teacher_id from course where course = 'Math')
```

Comment: I want to get all teacher who does not teachs math but still i get teacher1.

Comment: because teacher 1 also teaches other subject. thats why it is showing teacher 1

Comment: If a teacher teaches 2 courses of which one of maths this fails.

Comment: @Ben see the edit now it will show the accurate result

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande You have a typo in `Maths`, an extra `s`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB yes man when i create tables in my database i inserted `maths` instead of `math` thats why it is like that. but thanks will edit the one

Comment: You could use SQL Fiddle to generate the text DDL directly from OP's question ;-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB how to do that man. I didnt knew about it. can you tell me ?

Comment: Go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ select your database vendor, click Text to DDL, copy paste OP's table, give appropriate table name. The DDL will be generated in the schema panel.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from Teacher 
join Course 
on Teacher.teacher.id = Course.teacher.id 
where Course.course != 'Math'
```

Comment: If a teacher teaches 2 courses of which one of maths this fails.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    t.name
from teacher t 
left join course c 
on c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id 
    where  c.course_id <> 2
```

Comment: If a teacher teaches 2 courses of which one of maths this fails.

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a description